# mage/translation not working magento 2 (translation issue)

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme

I am working on pdp page (mobile view), in drop down i need to show **out of stock** if qty is out of stock and **low stock** if qty is low stock, it is working as expected but it is not getting translated to other language (translation issue). My file is `SwatchRenderer.js` (`D:app\design\frontend\Alshaya\mcmenablank\Magento_Swatches\web\js\SwatchRenderer.js`)

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'jquery/ui', 'mage/translate'], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';
     //code here
     .......
     .......
                if (stockStatus === undefined) {
                    label += ' - ' + $.mage.__('Out of stock');
                }
                if (stockStatus) {
                    /* Display Low stock message */
                    if (stockStatus['qty'] <= stockStatus['notifyQty']) {
                        label += ' - ' + $.mage.__('low stock');
                    }
                }
        ............................
        ...............................
```

Comment: Delete `js-translation.json` in `pub/static/frontend/VendorTheme` and try to run static content deploy again.

Comment: "Out of stock":"\u0646\u0641\u062f\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0645\u064a\u0629"   coming in js-translation.json but it is not fetching in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code below to your phtml file.

```
<?php
$_data = array(
    'Out of stock' => __('Out of stock'),
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery", "mage/translate"], 
    function ($) {
        $.mage.translate.add(<?php echo Zend_Json::encode($_data) ?>)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Remember - Zend_Json::encode would need to be updated to \Laminas\Json\Json::decode for Magento 2.4.6 onwards